# Magento2 not able to get customer data in observer

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I am using Magento 2.4.1, made observer. Event name is checkout_submit_all_after. I want to
update order data, customer data, customer address data. Updating Order data is succeeded, but Other data failed. I use "$customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);" to get customer data, but returned nodata.
Please teach me I can't get customer data.

```
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;

class OrderCreateObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $request;
    protected $customerRepository;

    public function __construct(
        RequestInterface $request,
        CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,

    ){
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $params = $this->request->getParams();

        $customerId = $order->getCustomerId();
        
        $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);
        $customer->setCustomAttribute('updatecolumn', $params['updatecolumn']);

        $this->customerRepository->save($customer);

    }
}
```

**updated**

$customer->getCustomAttribute('updatecolumn')->getValue()

was worked, after

$customer->setCustomAttribute('updatecolumn', $params['updatecolumn']);

but data was not saved

Answer (score 0):

if you want to made these changes after order submit better you use this event

```
<event name="sales_order_place_after">
    <observer name="order_create_observer" instance="Example\Details\Observer\OrderCreateObserver" / >
</event>
```

instead of

```
<event name="checkout_submit_all_after">
    <observer name="order_create_observer" instance="Example\Details\Observer\OrderCreateObserver" / >
</event>
```

Comment: thank you. observer worked, but customer data did not update(customer_entity table did not update.)